# Installation freezes at "Unzipping Dart SDK" in android studio

Tags: android-studio, dart

Recently I had installed a flutter plugin in android studio. And when I chose to create a new project, it asked me for the flutter sdk. I chose "Install SDK". It froze at ""Unzipping Dart SDK".

I left it in this state for more than 3hrs, but there has been no response.

Please can any one help me to continue....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bug in flutter (that it doesn't report a useful error), there are quite a few reports like [this one](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11698) in the issue tracker.

You should try running `flutter doctor` from a command prompt, as this will perform the same job of downloading/extracting the Dart SDK but may be easier to troubleshoot.

From the issue linked above, it seems like a common issue is permissions - having it in a location like Program Files that non-Admins can't write to and therefore you need to run as Admin for it to work. A better fix would be to not put Flutter inside a protected path like `C:\Program Files`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Windows 7) i found that the flutter sdk folder permission was set to be readonly, once i changed the folder permission... it works fine